# Set Duplicate value as null (or) empty How ? using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

If i'm binding multiple dataset into a single table using MySQL, but there are some columns with duplicate value I need to set those duplicate value as null (or) empty How ?
Note: Can't touch the data.....
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want to set both value to `null`? Or just one of them? Either way, these `null`s will also cause duplicates. Could you be more specific? (Like examples, what have you tried, ...)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the duplicates without making a new table

ALTER IGNORE TABLE Employeefoo ADD UNIQUE (title, SID)

Comment: Well thanks for the reply..... But i can't do any thing in db.... NO insert (or) alter.... bcoz the data well collapse.....

Comment: If u cant do anything with DB or cant change the data, how can u make a change?

Comment: or if u can  delete the data 

 " delete
from employee using employee,
    employee e1
where employee.id > e1.id
    and employee.first_name = e1.first_name "